# setOpaque(false) not work with JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with the JTextArea . I wanted to make invisible the JTextArea with setOpaque(false) but it does not work.
This is my code:

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextArea tA;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public NewClass() {

        this.setTitle("Test");

        initJpanel();

        initTextArea();

        this.setSize(800, 640);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setResizable(false);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setContentPane(panel);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass();
    }

    private void initJpanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        panel.setSize(800, 640);
        panel.setLocation(0, 0);
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    private void initTextArea() {

        tA= new JTextArea();
        tA.setOpaque(false);
        tA.setLineWrap(true);
        tA.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        tA.setSize(400, 100);
        tA.setLocation(0, 0);
        tA.setOpaque(false);
        //tA.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 90));
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tA);
        scrollPane.setSize(400, 100);
        scrollPane.setLocation(0, 0);
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        //scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 90));
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

I tried this code but does not work. The JTextArea does not become transparent.

Comment: @BackSlash: if I remove the layout manager the textarea appears smaller. I don't want to use any type of layout because I want to put where I want.

Comment: Lo vuoi trasparente che si vede il testo oppure invisibile completamente? [do you want it transparent but with visible text or completely invisible?]. In the second case you shoud use "setVisible(false)" but I don't think is the case. By the way if you are using MAC OSX let we know because things like opacity don't behave the same under mac environment.

Comment: @MassimoZampieri You didn't get the point. You **are** removing the layout manager by using `panel.setLayout(null);`. You should [use Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead, they can save you a lot of work.

Comment: @trashgod: what I want is remove the with background of the textarea. With other component, when I used setopaque(false) becomes invisible.
Also removing the setopaque (false ) and putting setBackground ( new Color ( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) ) does not become transparent.

Comment: Working on mac? (always translate in english your posts)

Comment: no I am using windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set the scrollPane's viewport opacity as well:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```